# JS How to add variable into span

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm total newbie, and i want to know how to put a var x into  the span tag so i can change the color of the variable.

```
function wyr()
{
    var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    if(x <= 33)

        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x + '<span style="color:red;">%</span>';

    else if(x >= 34 && x <= 66)

        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x + '<span style="color:blue;">%</span>';

    else

        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x + '<span style="color:yellow;">%</span>';
}
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [string/template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = `<span style="color:red;">${x}</span>`;
```

Use backticks instead of quotes and your variable goes inside the ${}. Everything between the ticks will get interpolated into a string, including the variable inside the ${}.

Comment: And note the use of backticks (`) instead of normal quotation marks

Comment: Thank you, it worked.I didn't knew about that, still learning :)

Comment: Thanks David. Updated my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if all you want to do at the end of the day is change a span's color, skip directly to method 3.

There are many ways of doing so:

1- Basic string concatenation:

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">' + x + '</span>';
```

2- Template literals (where you need to use backticks (`) instead of quotes):

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x + `<span style="color:red;">${x}</span>`;
```

3- **Why not simply use CSS to change the color?** Assuming you insert your `<span>` directly into your HTML, and that this span has an ID of 'mySpan', you can do:

```
var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');
span.style.color = 'red';
```